# Error: object of abstract class type is not allowed when create an instance of a abstract class

Tags: c++, instance

I'm trying to create a .dll file. I define an class

```
class Contactmodel

public:
Contactmodel();
virtual ~Contactmodel();
```

Then, I try to create an instance of this class

```
virtual Contactmodel *clone() const {return new Contactmodel();}
```

But when I compile, it causes the error: object of abstract class type is not allowed when create an instance of a abstract class

Could you please show me what I did wrong to create an instance and how to fix it? thank you!

My header file

```
#pragma once
// contactmodelCohesive.h

#include "contactmodel/src/contactmodelmechanical.h"

#ifdef Cohesive_LIB
#  define Cohesive_EXPORT EXPORT_TAG
#elif defined(NO_MODEL_IMPORT)
#  define Cohesive_EXPORT
#else
#  define Cohesive_EXPORT IMPORT_TAG
#endif

namespace cmodelsxd {
    using namespace itasca;

    class ContactModelCohesive : public ContactModelMechanical {
    public:

        Cohesive_EXPORT ContactModelCohesive();
        Cohesive_EXPORT virtual ~ContactModelCohesive();
        virtual void                copy(const ContactModel *c);
        virtual void                archive(ArchiveStream &); 

        virtual QString  getName() const { return "Cohesive"; }
        virtual void     setIndex(int i) { index_=i;}
        virtual int      getIndex() const {return index_;}

        enum PropertyKeys { 
              kwKn=1
            , kwKs                            
            , kwFric   
            , kwForce
            , kwMoment
            , kwState
            , kwRGap
            , kwConRad
            , kwSig
            , kwTau 
            , kwEmod
            , kwKRatio
            , kwTenStrength
            , kwCoh 
            , kwPhiF
            , kwPhiD
            , kwInelasDeform
            , kwDamagevar
            , kwAlpha
            , kwLamda
            , kwwsig
            , kwwcoh
        };

        virtual QString  getProperties() const { 
            return " kn"
                   ",ks"
                   ",fric"
                   ",coh_force"
                   ",coh_moment"
                   ",state"
                   ",rgap"
                   ",con_rad"
                   ",sigma"
                   ",tau"
                   ",emod"
                   ",kratio"
                   ",ten_strength"
                   ",cohesion"
                   ",phi_f"
                   ",phi_d"
                   ",in_deform"
                   ",D_var"
                   ",alpha"
                   ",lamda"
                   ",w_sig"
                   ",w_coh";
        }

        enum FishCallEvents { fActivated=0, fBondBreak };
        virtual QString  getFishCallEvents() const { return "contact_activated,contact_break"; }
        virtual QVariant getProperty(uint i,const IContact *) const;
        virtual bool     getPropertyGlobal(uint i) const;
        virtual bool     setProperty(uint i,const QVariant &v,IContact *);
        virtual bool     getPropertyReadOnly(uint i) const;


         enum MethodKeys { kwDeformability=1
                        , kwcohBond
                        , kwcohUnbond
        };

        virtual QString  getMethods() const {
            return "deformability"
                   ",bond"
                   ",unbond";
        }

        virtual QString  getMethodArguments(uint i) const; 

        virtual bool     setMethod(uint i,const QVector<QVariant> &vl,IContact *con=0); // Base 1 - returns true if timestep contributions need to be updated

        virtual uint     getMinorVersion() const;

        virtual bool     validate(ContactModelMechanicalState *state,const double &timestep);

        //virtual bool    endPropertyUpdated(const QString &name,const IContactMechanical *c);

        virtual bool     forceDisplacementLaw(ContactModelMechanicalState *state,const double &timestep);

        virtual DVect2   getEffectiveTranslationalStiffness() const { DVect2 ret = effectiveTranslationalStiffness_; return ret;}
        virtual DAVect   getEffectiveRotationalStiffness() const {if (!cohProps_) return DAVect(0.0); return cohProps_->coh_AngStiff_;}

        virtual ContactModelCohesive *clone() const { return NEWC(ContactModelCohesive()); }

        virtual double   getActivityDistance() const {return rgap_;}

        virtual bool     isOKToDelete() const { return !isBonded(); }

        virtual void     resetForcesAndMoments() { cohF(DVect(0.0)); cohM(DAVect(0.0));}

        virtual bool     checkActivity(const double &gap) { return (gap <= rgap_ || isBonded()); }

        virtual bool     isBonded() const { return cohProps_ ? (cohProps_->coh_state_==3) : false; }

        bool     hasPBond() const {return cohProps_ ? true:false;}
        const double & rgap() const {return rgap_;}
        void     rgap(const double &d) {rgap_=d;}
        int      cohState()   const {return hasPBond() ? cohProps_->coh_state_: 0;}   
        void     cohState(int i) { if(!hasPBond()) return; cohProps_->coh_state_=i;}
        double   cohKn() const {return (hasPBond() ? (cohProps_->coh_kn_) : 0.0);}
        void     cohKn(const double &d) { if(!hasPBond()) return; cohProps_->coh_kn_=d;}
        double   cohKs() const {return (hasPBond() ? (cohProps_->coh_ks_) : 0.0);}
        void     cohKs(const double &d) { if(!hasPBond()) return; cohProps_->coh_ks_=d;}
        double   cohFric() const {return (hasPBond() ? (cohProps_->coh_fric_) : 0.0);}
        void     cohFric(const double &d) { if(!hasPBond()) return; cohProps_->coh_fric_=d;}
        double   cohTen() const {return (hasPBond() ? (cohProps_->coh_ten_) : 0.0);}
        void     cohTen(const double &d) { if(!hasPBond()) return; cohProps_->coh_ten_=d;}
        double   cohLamda() const {return (hasPBond() ? (cohProps_->coh_lamda_) : 0.0);}
        void     cohLamda(const double &d) { if(!hasPBond()) return; cohProps_->coh_lamda_=d;}
        double   cohAlpha() const {return (hasPBond() ? (cohProps_->coh_alpha_) : 0.0);}
        void     cohAlpha(const double &d) { if(!hasPBond()) return; cohProps_->coh_alpha_=d;}
        double   cohInelas() const {return (hasPBond() ? (cohProps_->coh_inelas_) : 0.0);}
        void     cohInelas(const double &d) { if(!hasPBond()) return; cohProps_->coh_inelas_=d;}
        double   cohDvar() const {return (hasPBond() ? (cohProps_->coh_dvar_) : 0.0);}
        void     cohDvar(const double &d) { if(!hasPBond()) return; cohProps_->coh_dvar_=d;}
        double   cohCoh() const {return (hasPBond() ? (cohProps_->coh_coh_) : 0.0);}
        void     cohCoh(const double &d) { if(!hasPBond()) return; cohProps_->coh_coh_=d;}
        double   cohPhiD() const {return (hasPBond() ? (cohProps_->coh_phid_) : 0.0);}
        void     cohPhiD(const double &d) { if(!hasPBond()) return; cohProps_->coh_phid_=d;}
        double   cohPhiF() const {return (hasPBond() ? (cohProps_->coh_phif_) : 0.0);}
        void     cohPhiF(const double &d) { if(!hasPBond()) return; cohProps_->coh_phif_=d;}
        double   cohwsig() const {return (hasPBond() ? (cohProps_->w_sig) : 0.0);}
        void     cohwsig(const double &d) { if(!hasPBond()) return; cohProps_->w_sig=d;}
        double   cohwcoh() const {return (hasPBond() ? (cohProps_->w_coh) : 0.0);}
        void     cohwcoh(const double &d) { if(!hasPBond()) return; cohProps_->w_coh=d;}
        DVect    cohF() const {return hasPBond() ? cohProps_->coh_F_: DVect(0.0);}
        void     cohF(const DVect &f) { if(!hasPBond()) return; cohProps_->coh_F_=f;}
        DAVect   cohM() const {return hasPBond() ? cohProps_->coh_M_: DAVect(0.0);}
        void     cohM(const DAVect &m) { if(!hasPBond()) return; cohProps_->coh_M_=m;}
        DVect2   cohTransStiff() const {return hasPBond() ? cohProps_->coh_TransStiff_: DVect2(0.0);}
        void     cohTransStiff(const DVect2 &f) { if(!hasPBond()) return; cohProps_->coh_TransStiff_=f;}
        DAVect   cohAngStiff() const {return hasPBond() ? cohProps_->coh_AngStiff_: DAVect(0.0);}
        void     cohAngStiff(const DAVect &m) { if(!hasPBond()) return; cohProps_->coh_AngStiff_=m;}

        const DVect2 & effectiveTranslationalStiffness()  const          {return effectiveTranslationalStiffness_;}
        void           effectiveTranslationalStiffness(const DVect2 &v ) {effectiveTranslationalStiffness_=v;}

    private:
        static int index_;

        struct cohProps {
            cohProps() : coh_kn_(0.0), coh_ks_(0.0), coh_fric_(0.0), coh_state_(0), coh_ten_(0.0), coh_coh_(0.0), 
                        coh_alpha_(1.0), coh_lamda_(0.0), coh_phid_(0.0), coh_phif_(0.0), coh_dvar_(0.0), coh_inelas_(0.0),
                        coh_F_(DVect(0.0)), coh_M_(DAVect(0.0)), coh_TransStiff_(0.0), coh_AngStiff_(0.0) {}
            // parallel bond
            int     coh_state_;         // Contact mode - 0 (NBNF), 1 (NBFT), 2 (NBFS), 3 (B)
            double  coh_kn_;           // normal stiffness
            double  coh_ks_;           // shear stiffness
            double  kn0;
            double  ks0;
            double  coh_fric_;          // Moment contribution factor 
            double  coh_ten_;          // normal strength 
            double  coh_coh_;           // friction angle
            double  ten0;
            double  coh0;
            double  coh_inelas_;           // friction angle
            double  coh_alpha_;   // soften normal stiffness
            double  coh_lamda_;      // soften normal stiffness
            double  coh_phid_;      // soften normal stiffness
            double  phid0;
            double  coh_phif_;      // soften normal stiffness
            double  coh_dvar_;      // soften normal stiffness
            DVect   coh_F_;            // Force in parallel bond
            DAVect  coh_M_;            // moment in parallel bond
            double  mn;
            double  ms;
            double  w_sig;
            double  w_coh;
            DVect2  coh_TransStiff_;    // (Normal,Shear) Translational stiffness of the parallel bond
            DAVect  coh_AngStiff_;      // (Normal,Shear) Rotational stiffness of the parallel bond
        };

        void   updateEffectiveStiffness(ContactModelMechanicalState *state);

        DVect3 cohData(const IContactMechanical *con) const; // Bond area and inertia
        DVect2 cohSMax(const IContactMechanical *con) const; // Maximum stress (tensile,shear) at bond periphery
        double cohShearStrength(const double &cohArea) const;      // Bond shear strength

        double      rgap_;      // reference gap for the linear part

        cohProps *   cohProps_;     // The parallel bond properties

        DVect2  effectiveTranslationalStiffness_;

    }; //ContactModelCohesive
} // cmodelsxd
```

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), looks like `Contactmodel` has a pure abstract function which is not listed here. If that's the case, you cannot create an instance of an abstract class.

Comment: Part of the meaning of "abstract class" is that it cannot be instantiated.   Essentially it means that your class has a pure virtual member function which (1) prevents instantation and (2)  requires a derived class to specialise all inherited pure virtuals, otherwise the derived class is also abstract.

Comment: Thank you, I mean to create a class, not abstract. I check my code but seem I did not define any pure abstract function (virtual function() = 0). But do not know why the compiler thinks my class is abstract

Comment: If you haven't declared a function as pure virtual, then you have inherited from a class that does.   In that case, it is necessary to specialise ALL the inherited pure virtual functions as well, otherwise your class cannot be instantiated.

Comment: Yeah, thank Peter. It would be my problem as I skip to override some functions in the base class as it is not needed for my work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create an instance of `Contactmodel` if `Contactmodel` is an abstract class (i.e. contains a pure virtual function). The `clone` is usually defined as a pure virtual function in a base class, the overloaded in the derived, like

```
struct IClonable 
{
    virtual IClonable* clone() const = 0;
    virtual ~IClonable() = default;
};

class Foo: public IClonable
{
public:    
    Foo* clone() const override
    {
        return new Foo{*this};
    }
};

int main() 
{
    Foo* foo = new Foo;
    Foo* clone = foo->clone();
    delete clone;
    delete foo;
}
```

or, with smart pointers

```
#include <memory>

struct IClonable 
{
    virtual std::unique_ptr<IClonable> clone() const = 0;
    virtual ~IClonable() = default;
};

class Foo: public IClonable
{
public:    
    std::unique_ptr<IClonable> clone() const override
    {
        return std::make_unique<Foo>(*this);
    }
};

int main() 
{
    std::unique_ptr<IClonable> up_foo{new Foo};
    std::unique_ptr<IClonable> up_clone = up_foo->clone();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I define a normal class without any pure virtual function (virtual function() = 0). But the compiler understands my class is abstract and does not allow to define an instance. Do you know any reason that making the compiler think it is an abstract class? thank you

Comment: @TươngNhư Do you inherit from an abstract class and don't override a pure virtual function? That's the only reason I can think of.

Comment: Thank you, it would be the problem. Actually, I'm trying to combine a code to an open source code. So I skip some functions as it is not necessary for my work. Maybe, one of the functions I skiped is virtual and it hasn't been overrided yet.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for having abstract base classes is to provide an interface that concrete classes must implement. You are not supposed to create instances of the abstract base class.

Make `clone()` a pure virtual function and do not implement it in the base class. Implement it only in the concrete classes.

```
virtual Contactmodel *clone() const = 0;
```